# Given a sequence of events, if the probability associated to each event is bigger than $0$, does it follow that $\bigcap_n A_n\ne\emptyset$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, probability-theory, proof-explanation, solution-verification

Let us start with a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$, with $\{A_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ denoting a decreasing sequence of events. Is it true that
$$\mathbb{P}(A_n)\geq\varepsilon>0\text{ for all }n\implies\bigcap_n A_n\ne\emptyset\tag{1}$$
?

---

In general, I am tempted to say that $(1)$ is not necessarily true, since it could happen that even if each of the set $A_n$ has a positive probability associated to itself, the intersection of all the considered sets $A_n$ can be empty.

---

---

Am I wrong? If so, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked two completely different questions in the title and in the body of the question. If we only assume that the probabilities are positive then the intersection indeed can be empty. Consider $\Omega=(0,1]$ with the Borel sigma-algebra and the Lebesgue measure on it. Then take $A_n=(0,\frac{1}{n}]$, this is indeed a decreasing sequence of events with positive probability, and their intersection is empty.

On the other hand if $A_n$ is decreasing and there is some $\epsilon>0$ such that $\mathbb{P}(A_n)\geq\epsilon$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ then by the continuity from above property of a measure it follows that $\mathbb{P}(\cap_{n=1}^\infty A_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(A_n)\geq\epsilon$. So in particular the intersection is not empty.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for my mistake. Thank you a lot, your answer is extremely clear